# How to set JavaFx HTML Editor to a smaller width

Tags: javafx, html-editor

I have a HTML editor in a Pane container 355px in width. The editor gets cut on the right side where the width overlaps the containing pane. How can I set the HTML Editor's width to a smaller width than that of the parent container?

Please note that I'm on JavaFx SceneBuilder 2 and dragging the width to something smaller than that of the Parent container just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While on Scene Builder 2.0 the HTML editor can't be resized, this just affects the preview (well, maybe it hiddens some other controls,...). If this is really a problem, instead of adding the HTML editor there, just place a container with a proper `fx:id` and later on the controller add the editor as a child of that container.

Assuming you have the editor added on your FXML, and the width of your scene is 355px, as you say, the first preview of the application will have the toolbars cut, and there won't be any overflow button until you resize the window. Only then, the toolbars will be resized and the overflows will appear.

To overcome this problems and let the editor be resized right after the application is launched, without the manual resize, the workaround is to find the toolbars of the editor, and resize them.

```
@FXML private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Platform.runLater(()->{
        htmlEditor.lookupAll("ToolBar")
                  .forEach(node->((ToolBar)node).setPrefWidth(355));
    });
}
```

[image: Scene 355x300 px]

Note the hardcoded width value, for the sake of simplicity.